# Checkbox Check all functionality which is loaded from Json via Ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, checkbox

[I have JSON loaded checkboxes here in the grid. I want check/uncheckall functionality on these checkboxes. Directly we can't manipulate on these checkboxes as these are not there in dom. These are loaded through ajax call]

Please can someone help me here? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE344.png)

Comment: What do you mean by not in DOM? Through script you are creating DOM.

Comment: Provide us some code, how checkboxes are created & how they look like in code then they are created.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(".parent").change(function () {
        $(".child").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
});
```

We have to use ajaxComplete() here as the elements are not there in DOM.